# Make Completionhandler Work in For-Loop for Image Fetching

Tags: swift, firebase, for-loop, closures, completionhandler

I am fetching user images from Firebase. A user can have up to 6 images uploaded in the Database. I want do download the images into a CollectionView in correct order (0-6).

When i try to use CompletionHandler it doesn't work as i wish. The reloading of the CollectionView is done long before the images are fetched, no images are shown, because the images are put in the array after reloadData is called.

Would appreciate help with this issue.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        downloadAndReload()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayImages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "swipeCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ProfileCardCollectionViewCell
        let image = self.arrayImages[indexPath.item]
        cell.swipeProfileImage.image = image
        print("lägger ut cell")
        return cell
    }

    func downloadAndReload(){
        cachedImage(completion: { message in
            print(message)
            self.swipeCollectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }


    func cachedImage(completion: @escaping (_ message: String) -> Void){
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
            for i in 0...6{

                let url = URL(string: uid+String(i))

                SDWebImageManager.shared.loadImage(with: url, options: .refreshCached, progress: .none ,completed: { (image, data, error, _, _, _) in

                    if let error = error{
                        print("Couldn't download image")
                        self.downloadImage(i: i, completion: {_ in

                        })
                    }
                    else{
                        print("Could download image")
                        self.arrayImages.append(image!)
                    }
                })
            }
            completion("DONE")
        }

    }

    func downloadImage(i: Int, completion: @escaping (_ fetchWorked: String) -> Void){
        print("Downloading Image")

        let g = DispatchGroup()
        g.enter()
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
            let imagesStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profilepic/").child(uid+String(i))

            imagesStorageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                guard let url = url else { return }

                SDWebImageManager.shared.loadImage(with: url, options: .refreshCached, progress: .none ,completed: { (image, data, error, _, _, _) in

                    if let error = error{
                    }
                    else{
                        self.arrayImages.append(image!)
                    }
                })

                g.leave()

            }
            g.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                completion("Done")
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you got nested closures, so when you call:

```
SDWebImageManager.shared.loadImage(with: url, options: .refreshCached, progress: .none ,completed: { (image, data, error, _, _, _) in

                if let error = error{
                    print("Couldn't download image")
                    self.downloadImage(i: i, completion: {_ in

                    })
                else{
                    print("Could download image")
                    self.arrayImages.append(image!)
                }
            })
```

Everything inside it will only be called when "loadImage" finishes, therefore your "for" will call "SDWebImageManager.shared.loadImage" 6 times, and then then call "completion("Done")".

So your code will call "completion("Done")" before it finishes processing the images, therefore reloading the data when there is no images or possibly a couple.

You need to wait for the fetching to finish before calling reloadData(), it will depend on your needs, but you could just fetch the images as needed, when you're gonna set the images to the cell content, call to fetch images (from cache first or download if not available) then just update where they're shown.
This way your application will appear more dynamically on the screen, also setup placeholder images.

Comment: Thank you, problem is CollectionView needs to know how big arrayImages.count is. I only want uploaded images to be shown in cells. That is why i wanted to download all images first before reloading.

Comment: But in your code it is hardcoded that it is always 6, if you know it is always 6, then its a fixed value.
Remember how Facebook and Instagram are, they don't necessarily show all images, they load on demand and then update the size (number of cells), as images are loaded.
If you want to download them first, then it's better to call the function before you present the view but that will depend on how you application is structured(